# Tableservice.insertorReplace does not push all data to the table

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm going mental about this case. I have a function and an object with some data to send to a table in the azure storage.

my code on azure looks like this:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService(process.env.AzureWebJobsStorage);

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

   // Doing some query and creating the object





    context.log("Sending data to the table..")
    context.log("size of resultBlob: " + Object.keys(resultsBlob).length) //here will be 971 items
    
    var fullcounter = 0 // checking if the for cycles for all values 
    for (var item in resultsBlob) {
        fullcounter = fullcounter + 1 //adding one
        
  

        let insertEntity = {
            PartitionKey: resultsBlob[item].country,
            RowKey: resultsBlob[item].StoreNumb,
            LastBackup: resultsBlob[item].LastBackup
        };

      
        tableSvc.insertOrReplaceEntity('TestTable', insertEntity, function (error, result, response) {
            if (error) {
                context.log("There was an error while sending the data to the table")
            }
        });


    }
    context.log("Printing full counter" + fullcounter) //this will be 971
    




};
```

if you notice in the comments, I have an object with 971 entries and I'm trying to push all to the table, when the function is executed, the var fullcounter has value 971 and it's correct. But when I go to see the data in the table it's always less.
If I run multiple time it might vary from 600 to 700 but never the full size of the object.

If I try the same locally from my pc, all 971 items are delivered to the table. The only difference is that there is a main function and not a timer function from azure.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You have to keep in mind that your for loop is synchronous whereas insertOrReplaceEntity operation is asynchronous. You may want to use asynchronous loop.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for your answer, do you have any example for me?

Comment: Not handy ATM but please take a look at Bluebird library for asynchronous loops (Promise.map etc.).

Comment: Hi Guarav, I've fixed it with creating a async function with the for loop ;
in the function before the tableserivce i've inserted a 
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0200))

Like this looks like it's working

Comment: Awesome! Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing your question and including it there.

Answer (score 0):

After Gaurav suggestion my code has changed as following:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService(process.env.AzureWebJobsStorage);

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

    // Doing some query and creating the object






    context.log("size of resultBlob: " + Object.keys(resultsBlob).length) //here will be 971 items


    var fullcounter = 0

    async function insertAsync(resultsBlob) {
        for (var item in resultsBlob) {
            fullcounter = fullcounter + 1

            //context.log(item,resultsBlob[item].found)

            let insertEntity = {
                PartitionKey: resultsBlob[item].country,
                RowKey: resultsBlob[item].StoreNumb,
                LastBackup: resultsBlob[item].LastBackup
            };

            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0200))
            //check if the entity exists, if exists will replace, otherwise will create a new one - Status table
            tableSvc.insertOrReplaceEntity('TestTable', insertEntity, function (error, result, response) {
                if (error) {
                    context.log("There was an error while sending the data to the table", JSON.stringify(error))// Insert table entity error
                }
            });



        }
        return fullcounter
    }

    context.log("Sending data to the table..")
    await insertAsync(resultsBlob)
    context.log("Printing full counter" + fullcounter)





};
```